# Mongoose ignoring empty fields while aggregating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

collection: A

Document:

```
{
color: '',
age: 22,
name: 'John'
}
```

Collection: B

Document:

```
{
name:'John',
marks: 100
}
```

I am performing an aggregate by joining both the collections something like this

```
A.aggregate([
    {
      $match: filters
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'B',
        localField: 'name',
        foreignField: 'name',
        as: 'alias1',
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$alias1'
    },
    {
      $project: {
        color: '$color',
        marks: '$alias1.marks',
       }
}])
```

The result I get is:

```
{
marks:100
}
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
{
color: '',
marks: 100
}
```

I assume since the color field is empty , the aggregate is ignoring it by default.

Basically, I want to join two tables and get data for few fields. If aggregate doesn't solve this problem then any other way to achieve the desired result would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Does the aggregation work on non-empty `color` fields?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, but isn't alias1 is kind of a reference to collection B fields ?

Comment: Your sample is working as expected, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/bd-F3iMADfP

Comment: your query produces the result you need [see](https://mongoplayground.net/p/asoMnaCn5tl) but this to work it supposes that the lookup with max 1 from collection B, else you would need `$group`, try the stages one by one to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query :

```
A.aggregate([
    {
      $match: filters
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'B',
        localField: 'name',
        foreignField: 'name',
        as: 'alias1',
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$alias1'
    },
    {
      $project: {
        color: { $ifNull: [ "$color", "" ] },
        marks: '$alias1.marks',
       }
}])
```